# RadBusyIndicator not showing PRISM/MEF/WPF from ViewModel

Tags: wpf, mvvm, prism, backgroundworker, busyindicator

I am using MVVM/PRISM/MEF for my WPF application. It has one DataGrid with multiple records, and when one row is double clicked a separate view is added to region with multiple controls on it, the initialization of controls takes about 10 seconds for new screen, so thats why I want to show RadBusyIndicator during that time.

Following in the XAML

```xml
<!-- This is Main View -->
<!-- Module: MainModule, ViewModel: MainViewViewModel -->
<telerik:RadBusyIndicator IsBusy="{Binding IsBusy}" BusyContent="{Binding BusyContent}">
<!-- All PRISM regions are here -->
</telerik:RadBusyIndicator>
```

Its view model is

```cs
class MainViewViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        ImportingConstructor]
        public MainViewViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator, IRegionManager regionManager, IServiceLocator serviceLocator)
            :base(eventAggregator, regionManager, serviceLocator)
        {
            eventAggregator.GetEvent<BusyStateChangedEvent>().Subscribe(OnBusyStateChanged,ThreadOption.BackgroundThread);
        }

        #region BusyStateChanged

        private void OnBusyStateChanged(bool newState)
        {
            IsBusy = newState;
        }

        #endregion
}
```

And in other view when DataGrid row is double clicked ViewModelBase function is called, as follows

```cs
public class ViewModelBase
{
        private NavigationItem global_navItem = null;

        public virtual void OnNavigationItemChanged(NavigationItem item)
        {
            changeNav = true;
            global_navItem = item;

            //Firing event to change the state
            EventAggregator.GetEvent<BusyStateChangedEvent>().Publish(true);

            //Using BackgroundWorker, but its not showing any Busy Indicator as well
            var bw = new BackgroundWorker();
            bw.DoWork += bw_DoWork;
            bw.RunWorkerCompleted += bw_RunWorkerCompleted;

            bw.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

        void bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            //Setting busy indicator to false
            EventAggregator.GetEvent<BusyStateChangedEvent>().Publish(false);
        }

        void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            //DisplayView function is taking too long
            if (global_navItem != null) this.DisplayView(global_navItem);
        }
}

public void DisplayView(NavigationItem item)
        {
                    try
                    {
                        //This call is taking long as it initializes the View
                        MyCustomeUserControl view = this.ServiceLocator.GetInstance<MyCustomeUserControl>(item.viewName);

                        view.Region = this.Region;
                    }catch(Exception e)
                    {
                    }                   
        }
```

Events are being fired correctly and view is displayed correctly, but my problem is that Busy indicator is not shown at all, when I double click on DataGrid row the GUI become unresponsive, and after some time the new view appears. I am in doubt that this is problem of GUI thread being busy, but what can I do to avoid this, I have used `BackgroudWorker` already?

**EDIT**

1- I am raising PropertyChanged event for IsBusy Property. and I have already tried all options for Thread in event subscription. i.e. `Thread.BackgroundThread`, `Thread.UIThread` and `Thread.PublisherThread`. but no change.

2- I have tested `Thread.Sleep` rather that `DisplayView` in `bw_DoWork`, and its showing `RadBusyIndicator` properly, so it means that GUI controls are being initialized in GUI thread, no matter I have created a `BackgroundWorker` for it.

Comment: Code you posted seems ok. Just a stupid question (I mean no harm) Do you raise PropertyChanged event for IsBusy property? I just have to ask... And one more thing... [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122(v=pandp.20).aspx) it says *If you need to be able to update user-interface elements when an event is received, subscribe to receive the event on the user interface thread.* so if I were you I would switch ThreadOption.BackgroundThread on subscribing to BusyStateChangedEvent with ThreadOption.UIThread. But these are just ideas...

Comment: Thanks @ViktorLaCroix, Yes I am raising PropertyChanged event for `IsBusy` Property. and I have already tried all options for Thread in event subscription. i.e. `Thread.BackgroundThread`, `Thread.UIThread` and `Thread.PublisherThread`. but no change.

Comment: And now it gets interesting :) So would you please edit your question with this additional information? And please don't forget the fact that everything's ok when you switch DoWork method's body with Thread.Sleep

Comment: last thing I would try would be creating the instance of the view in the background then pass it as the result of DoWork and add it to the region in WorkerCompleted method. If it works with Thread.Sleep in DoWork it probably means that you are creating some work for UIThread in the background... it could be adding it to the region. if this doesn't help then I can't help you.

Comment: What I have analyzed is that `ServiceLocator` is taking time to initialize GUI controls, not the adding view to `Region` call. so I think it will not make a difference.

Comment: Yes... that's why I told you to move `view.Region = this.Region;` to WorkerCompleted after that it's sure there is no problem with code you provided, but with creating the instance of the view thus the problem is not in here... creating the instance uses the UI thread... you won't fix it by changing this code. You are adding work to invokationList of UI thread somewhere during creation of that view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have found a solution. For reference following post can be seen. I have implemented a child chrome-less window with RadBusyIndicator using the approach discussed in this post.

[Creating multiple UI Threads in WPF](http://eprystupa.wordpress.com/2008/07/28/running-wpf-application-with-multiple-ui-threads/)

Answer (score 1):

Would the indicator appear if you use `Thread.Sleep(5000)` instead of `this.DisplayView(global_navItem)`?

I assume showing the view will use the UI thread and this will block the UI no matter you use a `BackgroundWorker` or not.

**Edit:**

As it seems like your UI loading operation blocks the UI thread and so your BusyIndicator, you can try to host one of them in a different thread. An approach is explained in [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dwayneneed/archive/2007/04/26/multithreaded-ui-hostvisual.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, yes I tried with Thread.Sleep and its showing BusyIndicator properly. :(. What could be the any other approach for showing a busy indicator while a heavy GUI is being loaded?

Comment: This is not that easy. There are approaches to show a BusyIndicator in a different thread but the UI thread. I'll add a link to the answer soon.